# Verilog Error: ALU output shifts right one bit

Tags: verilog

For some reason in my Verilog code for an ALU, the outputs are calculated correctly, but then shifted to the right one bit.

I know this from monitoring signals with an embedded logic analyzer, and I'm 100% sure this is what's happening. I can't monitor aluout_A, but I can see aluout_M (which should be aluout_A with one cycle delay) as well as aluin1_A, aluin2_A, and alufunc_A.

If I'm not mistaken, the problem should be somewhere in the following code block, but I'm totally stumped as to why this is happening.

```
reg signed [(DBITS-1):0] aluout_A;
always @(alufunc_A or aluin1_A or aluin2_A) begin
    case(alufunc_A)
        {1'b0,OP2_ALU_ADD }: aluout_A=aluin1_A+aluin2_A;
        {1'b0,OP2_ALU_SUB }: aluout_A=aluin1_A-aluin2_A;
        {1'b0,OP2_ALU_AND }: aluout_A=aluin1_A&aluin2_A;
        {1'b0,OP2_ALU_OR  }: aluout_A=aluin1_A|aluin2_A;
        {1'b0,OP2_ALU_XOR }: aluout_A=aluin1_A^aluin2_A;
        {1'b0,OP2_ALU_NAND}: aluout_A=~(aluin1_A&aluin2_A);
        {1'b0,OP2_ALU_NOR }: aluout_A=~(aluin1_A|aluin2_A);
        {1'b0,OP2_ALU_NXOR}: aluout_A=~(aluin1_A^aluin2_A);
        {1'b0,OP2_ALU_MVHI}: aluout_A={aluin2_A[15:0],16'b0};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_F   }: aluout_A={31'b0,1'b0};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_EQ  }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A==aluin2_A};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_LT  }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A< aluin2_A};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_LTE }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A<=aluin2_A};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_EQZ }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A==32'b0};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_LTZ }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A< 32'b0};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_LTEZ}: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A<=32'b0};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_T   }: aluout_A={31'b0,1'b1};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_NE  }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A!=aluin2_A};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_GTE }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A>=aluin2_A};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_GT  }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A> aluin2_A};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_NEZ }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A!=32'b0};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_GTEZ}: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A>=32'b0};
        {1'b1,OP2_CMP_GTZ }: aluout_A={31'b0,aluin1_A> 32'b0};
        default:  aluout_A={DBITS{1'bX}};
    endcase
end

reg signed [(DBITS-1):0] aluout_M;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    aluout_M <= aluout_A;
end
```

Comment: This code looks correct to me

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem. For some reason (me being an idiot), in the logic analyzer only bits 31:1 were selected, explaining the seeming bit shift.